# White-space does not show up on select element option HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to align the text on the select element option. The data is being fetch from .CSV file using a function. And the function will return the `$code`. I fetch the data like this. As you see, I tried to use `\t`  to align the `$data[2]` since the length of $data[0] is not in the same length.

```
$code[] = str_pad($data[0], 5) . "\t" . ' - '. $data[2] . ' / ' . $data[1];
```

Then, I call that function on the select element option. Like this.

```
<select id="msic_2" name="msic_2" class="form-control">
          @if(isset($code))
                 @foreach($code as $key => $value)
                    <option value="{{$value}}" {{ populateForm(@old('msic'), $value, @$order_details->msic) }}>{{$value}}</option>
                 @endforeach
          @endif
</select>
```

All the data appear. But the problem is the `\t` property that I've used is not working on the displayed browser. When I tried to inspect element and check it, the `\t` property is functioning well. It seems like something was blocking my white-space from appear. Do you know how to fix/solve it?  Or do you know how to align the text in the drop-down list?

Answer (score -1):

Browsers seem to collapse whitespace (and tab) characters.

You can work around by either

- using the no-break space ([unicode U+00A0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)) instead of a regular space.

Copy and paste this character as the pad string parameter to [str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad)

- or using the HTML representation of a no-break space (`&nbsp;`)

Since this is a string and not a single character, `str_pad` would break. You would have to calculate how many `&nbsp;` strings you need to pad your string with.

Keep in mind that for this to work visually, you also need to render the `<select>` element with a fixed-proportional (monospace) font so that each character takes up the same space.

Comment: I already tried to use &nbsp; and str_pad as well. But it seem like not working. It read those things as a string instead.

Comment: _“PHP converts the tab character to several whitespace characters before they are output.”_ - what? No it doesn’t.

Comment: @CBroe you're right, removed that part, It's Firefox doing the conversion in my case.

Comment: @jat yes, as I said, `str_pad` will not work, since it would chop the `&nbsp;` anywhere, you'd get strings like `&nb` if 3 characters needed to be filled. Instead, you have to calculate how many `&nbsp;` you would have to insert, and then insert them.